# Fizzbuzz basic question, How to push replaced items into an empty array instead of just printing them out

Tags: javascript

So I am trying to solve

> " Create a function fizzbuzz that takes one number, n. fizzbuzz should
> loop through the numbers 1 through n and push each number into the
> results array using the following rules:
>
> 1. Push the string "fizz" in place of numbers divisible by 3.
> 2. Push the string "buzz" in place of numbers divisible by 5.
> 3. Push the string "fizzbuzz" in place of numbers divisible by both 3 and 5.
>
> Run the test console.log to check your work. "

My code is listed below

```
const results = [];

const fizzbuzz = (n) => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    let str = "";

    if (i % 3 === 0) str += "fizz"
    if (i % 5 === 0) str += "buzz"
    if (str === "") str = i;

    console.log(str);
  }
}
```

I just don't really know how to change my results so they are inside the array "results". My guess is to use array.push but I do not know where to include it in the code.

Comment: After all the if statements, use `results.push(str)`

Comment: Do that instead of `console.log(str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add it to the array every time you would print it, so call the push instead of the `console.log()`:

```
const results = [];

const fizzbuzz = (n) => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        let str = "";

        if (i % 3 === 0) str += "fizz"
        if (i % 5 === 0) str += "buzz"
        if (str === "") str = i;

        results.push(str) //Adding to array instead
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare your blank array inside your function, use the Array [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, and then return the array at end of function.

```
const fizzbuzz = (n) => {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    let str = "";

    if (i % 3 === 0) str += "fizz"
    if (i % 5 === 0) str += "buzz"
    if (str === "") str = i;

    results.push(str);
  }

  return results;
}
```

Just for fun, here is better way to solve it using [Ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). This method only ever requires 2 checks.

```
const fizzbuzz = (n) => {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    results.push(
      i % 3 === 0
        ? (i % 5 === 0 ? 'fizzbuzz' : 'fizz')
        : (i % 5 === 0 ? 'buzz' : i)
    );
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: The first method only requires two checks against `i` too.  :/

Comment: Ah ya, what I should've said is it only requires two checks. OP's method also checks for a blank string and has more operations (string concatenation).

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what I said in my comment to @ruleboy's answer I have now provided a very "nerdy" version of fizzbuzz *without* using the modulus operator at all.

In my snippet I use three counters: `i`, `n3` and `n5`. The result is *not easily readable*, therefore *I would never recommend using it in any production code*. But I thought it might be entertaining to have a look at it nonetheless:

```js
function fizzbuzz(n){
  const results = [];
  for (let i=1,n3=2,n5=4; 
       i<=n; 
       ++i,n3--?0:n3+=3,n5--?0:n5+=5) {
    results.push(n3?n5?i:"buzz":"fizz"+(n5?"":"buzz"));
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(fizzbuzz(30))
```

The expression `n3--?0:n3+=3,n5--?0:n5+=5` decrements the counters `n3` and `n5`. Every time any of the counters reaches the value `-1` (e. g.: `n3--==false`) I add the max value to each counter again (3 or 5). Very nerdy - as I already mentioned above! :D

Answer (score 0):

- Use `results.push` instead of `str += "fizz"`

Try this

```js
const fizzbuzz = (n) => {
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) results.push("fizzbuzz")
    else if (i % 3 === 0) results.push("fizz")
    else if (i % 5 === 0) results.push("buzz")
    else results.push(i)
  }

  return results;
}

// test
console.log(fizzbuzz(15))
```

Comment: Are you _really_ worrying about performance here?!? The total execution time for any "human digestible" list of numbers will be so small that we should not worry about it. Instead we should be looking at the readability of the code.